# Disabling the events of a button c#

Tags: c#, button

I am trying to make a trading game and I am trying to add a function that if you buy more than 10 items the buy button does not work anymore. I have started with an if statement

```
  int limit = 10;
int quantity = int.Parse(textBox13.Text);

        //Quantity 1
        if (quantity >= limit)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have gone beyond the limit!");
        }
```

I am just unsure what the code is that I should use. I have tried making the button invisible if you cant afford this however I would like to try this function.

Comment: Why can't you just disable the button once exceed the quantity?              
 You can disable the button btnId.Enable = false

Answer (score 1):

YourButtonIdHere.Enabled = false;

Comment: Go on Steve, give the OP and the community a little more explanation than this. :-)

Answer (score 1):

By setting ButtonID enable to False for disable the button. 
 Syntax: .Enabled = ;
 Example: btnID.Enabled = false;

Answer (score 1):

you can simply disable your `button`

```
button1.Enabled = false; // For Disable
button1.Enabled = true;  // For Enable
```

if it does not match with your criteria you can also only disable button's click event

```
button1.Click -= button1_Click; // For Disable
button1.Click += button1_Click; // For Enable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it when the text is being entered. Advantage of doing this is that you button will be enabled and disabled while entering text and you won't have to create new event for it. Hope it helps.

```
private void textBox13_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      if(Int.TryParse(textBox13.Text) > limit)
      {
button1.Enabled=false;
      }
      else
      {button1.Enabled=true;
      }
   }
   catch
   {
button1.Enabled=true;
   }
}
```